# Concatenate two dates to one column

Tags: date-time, calculated-column-formula

I am pretty basic user of SharePoint 2013 and I have this problem:
I have to create a calculated column with two dates in them to look like this:

From 21/2/2016 to 5/3/2016

but whatever I try, the dates are always displayed in a numeric string instead of regular date. I tried a lot of times to put TEXT in front of the column in the formula but I always get errors, no matter what combination of () "" && I use, there is always error.
Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a little cleaner, tested in SPO:

```
=CONCATENATE("From "&TEXT([Created], "dd/mm/yyyy")&" to "&TEXT([Modified], "dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

Yields:

> From 12/10/2015 to 12/10/2015

or this to not have the leading zeroes:

```
=CONCATENATE("From "&TEXT([Created], "d/m/yyyy")&" to "&TEXT([Modified], "d/m/yyyy"))
```

Yields:

> From 17/6/2015 to 18/2/2016

Comment: Note that the CONCATENATE function is for concatenating all sort of types. Since in this case they are all String (and & is a string concatenation) you can do with: ``"From " & TEXT([Created], "d/m/yyyy") & " to " & TEXT([Modified], "d/m/yyyy")``  *actually this CONCATENATE function only has 1 parameter, so does nothing*

Comment: This is just how I am accustomed to writing concatenated calculated columns,stemming from the 2003 days when calculated column documentation was sparse and most functions were prototyped in Excel

Comment: Oh it works, but its the & doing all the concat, and then the concatenate function gets 1 string as parameter.. does its work.. and outputs (the same) 1 string.. 2003?.. those were the days.. I can just recall the joyfull day I learned about the [Me] filter.. (and put 35000 records from an Orcale DB into SharePoint.. every night.. with a VBS script running for 5 hours 

Comment: thanks a lot! I can also see now, where I made a mistake....or mistakes, to be correct :D

Answer (score 1):

Use the following formula:

```
=("From " & DAY(Date1) & "/" & MONTH(Date1) & "/" &YEAR(Date1))
 &" to "
 & (DAY(Date2) & "/" & MONTH(Date2) & "/" & YEAR(Date2)
```

Comment: I only reformatted the Formula (SP ignores spaces and linebreaks when you paste this).. This Formula will indeed produce the same result as TEXT *only remember to add one more ) at the end* ... or ... *leave out the unnecessary ( )*

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you want `mm/dd/yyyy-mm/dd/yyyy` as a result.

```
=CONCATENATE(""&TEXT([Start Date], "mm/dd/yyyy")&"-"&TEXT([End Date], "mm/dd/yyyy"))
```